# PHP foreach in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to generate a database with uniqe codes a-z, A-Z and 0-9 with 6 digits or more(62^6=56800235584 uniqe codes)
Until now i have this code for sql:

```
    CREATE FUNCTION cod12() RETURNS VARCHAR(10)
BEGIN
  DECLARE chars VARCHAR(62);
  DECLARE result VARCHAR(6);
  DECLARE i INT;
  SET chars = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvxyz';
  SET result = '';
  SET i = 0;
  label: LOOP
    SET result = CONCAT(result, SUBSTRING(chars, FLOOR(RAND()*62) + 1, 1));
    SET i = i + 1;
    IF i = 10 THEN
      LEAVE label;
    END IF;
  END LOOP label;
  RETURN result;
```

when i call function is generate a random code, from my tests i can instert 10.000 codes per seconds.
PHP version, wich is perfect solution but can generate only 300 codes per seconds, and if fails will start from begining, is a simple foreach code:

```
$char=array('0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q');

    foreach ($char as $c) {


        foreach ($char as $c2) {
        foreach ($char as $c3) {
        foreach ($char as $c4) {

            echo $c['c'].$c2['c'].$c3['c'].$c4['c'].'<br>';
}}}}
```

Question:Loop in sql don't work, it generate only one code, how i can generate codes in order way(00,01,02...0t,0u,21,22,23,2b,2c...gj,gk,gl), not random, in sql command not php.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: do you use MySQL or MariaDB ? In MariaDB is a very nice SEQUENCE Engine to do this.

Comment: I hope you do realize, at the rate of 10.000 codes/sec, you end up being done after 66 days, to generate all 62^6?

Comment: not realy, i have  25 small servers(CPU 1.2 Ghz, 1GB ram), and i will split work.

Comment: Now MySQL, but i can change.

Comment: well that narrows it down to little to no time then :P  I've never attempted anything like this, and basically, I only commented on here because of the php tag. maybe this could be of some use? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cursors.html

Comment: Are you trying to build a rainbow table? Luckily that code wont even come close

Comment: something similar.